# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setTargetNode' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, node-modules

How can i solve issue. Please help me any one.

[image]

Comment: Please try to add more details like in which component creates above error. It will help us to find the issue.

Comment: targetRef
node_modules/reactstrap/node_modules/react-popper/lib/Target.js:40

Comment: This is not helping. I am asking you from where this error gets triggered. Above is an error message. Not a code. So please add a js code you have written which causes this error.

Comment: When i am starting react application then generate the this error. i think generate error for this => "reactstrap" component

Comment: How did you create the react app. Did you use create-react-app for new react app creation or some other way?. Please post your package.json.

Comment: Now on I solved issue.

Comment: What was the problem here?

Comment: Problems is node_modules inside reactstrap version issue. update to latest version and restart app

Comment: I have posted an answer. Please do accept. It helps others in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is version compatibility between different packages it seems. So updating the **reactstrap** package to its latest version solves the problem in this case. I am posting it here so it helps in case if anyone gets the same issue in future.

Please do check the package version and also do check the specific packages issues list(open/closed) in GitHub before asking a question here. Please make this as a habit.